# Footnotes in quote-blocks treated the same as footnotes for images

Tags: discussion, feature-request, markdown, images

**Update:  This is now a feature request.**

**Request**

That [number] in block-quotes not be changed to be links to any images included in the post.

**Justification**

Here's the current behavior...  In this answer ( [Is it possible for a substance to be thermally inert?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/95640/is-it-possible-for-a-substance-to-be-thermally-inert/95650#95650) )  I put in a quote from wiki, like so:

> Aerogel is a synthetic porous ultralight material derived from a gel, in which the liquid component of the gel has been replaced with a gas.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3guTf.png) The result is a solid with extremely low density[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE7I7.png) and low thermal conductivity. Nicknames include frozen smoke,[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtoYV.png) solid smoke, solid air, solid cloud, blue smoke

You can't see it, but the actual cut and pasted text looks like this:

> ... replaced with a gas.[ 1 ] The ...

Except I had to put in spaces around the number.  Note that these footnotes *belong to the wiki article*.  Now here are 3 images I'm putting into this answer:

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can't see it, but if you edit the article you'll see something like this:

> [ ! [ enter image description here ][ 1 ]][ 1 ]
>
> [ ! [ enter image description here ][ 2 ]][ 2 ]
>
> [ ! [ enter image description here ][ 3 ]][ 3 ]
>
> *more text, doesn't matter what it is*
>
> [ 1 ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3guTf.png
>
> [ 2 ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE7I7.png
>
> [ 3 ]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtoYV.png

That's all good.  The bad part is that the **wiki footnotes [ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 ]** in the block quote now point to the images.

I can't see the use case for quoted text -- ie, by definition **not** from this post -- pointing to the images **of** this post.  If you look at the wiki page, footnote 1 points here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel#cite_note-goldbook2007-1  .  But now, since SE rendering interprets [number], that footnote points to https://i.stack.imgur.com/3guTf.png .  Which is silly.

**Current expected behavior**

The only guidance I could find was here: 
 https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes .  This page doesn't speak to footnotes, so I don't know what expected behavior is.  So this is a FR asking for expected behavior to be what I want.  ;D

Specifically, that [number] in quote blocks should be excluded from resolving to image footnotes.

Comment: Where do you have the information that *...[number] in quote blocks should be excluded from resolving to image footnotes...* from?

Comment: @dot_Sp0T okay there it is.  Do let me know if this makes the case more clearly.

Comment: You've edited to show what's going on, but "According to me ... [number] in quote blocks should be excluded from resolving to image footnotes." sounds like a case of "what seems logical to my mind, but is not logical to the computer or the person(s) that programmed this", so while you might *want* it one way, that's not necessarily the way it is and I suspect this is more of a [meta-tag:feature-request] than a [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: @Mithrandir24601 is there a spec?  The only guidance I could find was here:  https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes  which doesn't speak to the question at hand.  But I'll change this to a feature request anyway, under the assumption that current expected behavior is indeed to rewrite footnotes from included text.

Comment: Those aren't footnotes, they are Markdown *reference-style links*. Links to external content work exactly the same; compare https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link. That Wikipedia happens to use square brackets for citation references is perhaps unfortunate, but ultimately the onus is on you to make your post look like you intended. If you absolutely must keep the reference numbers intact, you can escape the square brackets to cause them to appear verbatim in the post; compare https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#backslash. The spec is linked from /editing-help.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling just call me Don Quick-Oats.

Comment: @akaioi All right. \*makes a permanent annotation on akaioi's account\* Just kidding. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't need a new feature:

> ... replaced with a gas.[1] The ...
>
> [image]

You just need more backslashes (see `\[1]`?):

```
... replaced with a gas.\[1] The ...

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3guTf.png
```